# Mics for metal (screaming vocals)

Tags: microphone, metal, recommendations, vocals, gear

I was just wondering, if you record a metal band with a vocalist who screams, which microphones do you find to be the cleanest and most applicable?

Answer (score 4):

A friend of mine used an AKG D112 for vocals once before, and they turned out brilliantly. Of course this mic would be great for screaming vocals because it's used to a bit of a battering anyhow.

It might be worth a try.

It's all about how you play with the sound afterwards I guess.

Good luck :)

Comment: That's a super-weird selection for a vocal mic...but I kinda like that in a mic selection. ;-) Low-end, super-high SPL handling; thanks for sharing this interesting approach. Probably good for the ol' Black Metal cookie-monster vocals!

Comment: yeah! we were all shocked to see him using it for vocals..however, after we heard the sound that he got with it...just wow!

Answer (score 2):

i worked on a music project a while back that involved the vocalist screaming into the mic and a u47-clone tube mic did a great job. (so did the vocalist:) if you're on a budget and that's an overkill in price, look into techniques rather than models?

Answer (score 1):

I originally responded with the Audix OM7 before realizing you were looking for something studio, not live.  Don't ever record with mics intended for live performances.

I would go with a solid standard - AT4040 or 4047, Shure SM7, Neumann U87 if you want to pay a bit more - and put two pop filters in front. I've heard the RODE NTK is really solid for rock vocals, but have not heard it myself.

Don't limit yourself to one mic - it may take a while before you find the right mic for the these specific vocals.  Also be aware of the space you're working in.  Most mics do not sound good in an iso booth, they need a larger air space to sound right.